# TypeORM cascade option: cascade, onDelete, onUpdate

Tags: cascade, typeorm

Do cascade options in TypeORM overlap or do they have a completely different purpose? Their description in the documentation is very scarce and partly missing, or I couldn't find it.

IOW, do the following options

`{ cascade: "update" }` = `{ onUpdate: 'CASCADE' }`

`{ cascade: "remove" }` = `{ onDelete: 'CASCADE' }`

have the same effect?

Or the `cascade` option is only for the TypeORM use while `onUpdate` and `onDelete` are only for the DB schema (created by migration)?

Comment: dude where did you read about the cascade? I could not find it in their documentation.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

This is my conclusion of looking into it:

The `cascade` option **does not** affect the database column constraints, and I believe is used by TypeORM only in evaluating how to save entity relations to the database. We can define entities like this:

```js
@Entity()
class Book extends BaseEntity {
    @ManyToOne(() => Author, (author) => author.books, {
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    })
    public author?: Author
}

@Entity()
class Author extends BaseEntity {
    @OneToMany(() => Book, (book) => book.author, {
        cascade: true,
    })
    public books: Book[];
}
```

`onDelete` sets the `authorId` foreign key to CASCADE onDelete on `Book`. This means that when the author is deleted, the book is also deleted.

Setting `cascade: true` on `Author` tells TypeORM that if a new book is appended on an author and the author is saved, the new book should also be saved to the database. Like this:

```js
const author = await Author.findOne({ id: '123' });
author.books.push(new Book(...));
await author.save();
```

If cascade is not set on `Book`, the new book will not be saved to the database.

Comment: I guess setting `onDelete: 'CASCADE'`in the `@OneToMany`-side has no effect?

Comment: FYI: as of now cascade got extended. It is not just insert and update only anymore. Current options: `["insert", "update", "remove", "soft-remove", "recover"]`

Comment: Clear and concise explanation! Thanks @nomadoda

Comment: This is the best answer to solve the problem. Thanks!

Comment: The cascade option DOES affect the foreign key constraint. For this example, it will add "ON DELETE CASCADE" to the foreign key constraint of author → books for mysql.

Answer (score 2):

`onDelete: 'CASCADE` isn't supported in OneToMany relations yet. More context here: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/1913

Comment: I don't see how one can come to the conclusion that cascade delete isn't supported based on the issue @jstnno links to? The issue mention a bug that was fixed in 2019!