# Value of column in one to one relation using TypeORM + Postgres is null

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I'm trying to set up a simple one-to-one relation between an `item` and `item_name`. The entity looks as follows:

```
@Entity('item')
export class ItemEntity {
  @PrimaryColumn('integer')
  id: number;

  @OneToOne(() => ItemNameEntity)
  @JoinColumn()
  name: ItemNameEntity;

  // ... other props
}
```

`item-name.entity`

```
@Entity('item_name')
export class ItemNameEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  en: string;

  @Column()
  fr: string;

  // ... other properties
}
```

I insert an `item` using the following payload:

```
{
      id: 26,
      name: { en: 'English name', fr: 'French name' },
}
```

It stores the item as expected, and adds a `nameId` column. The problem is that it does not insert anything into `item_name`, and thus the `nameId` column is `null`.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55101273/6676781).

You have to set `cascade: true` on `name` relation in `ItemEntity`:

```js
@Entity('item')
export class ItemEntity {
  @PrimaryColumn('integer')
  id: number;

  @OneToOne(() => ItemNameEntity, { cascade: true })
  @JoinColumn()
  name: ItemNameEntity;

  // ... other props
}
```

Setting `cascade: true` on `ItemEntity` tells *TypeORM* that if a new *itemName* is *"linked"* on an *item* and the *item* is saved, the new *itemName* should also be saved to the database.

Example:

```js
const manager = getManager();
const item: ItemEntity = manager.create(ItemEntity, {
  id: 26,
  name: manager.create(ItemNameEntity, {
    en: 'English name',
    fr: 'French name'
  }),
});
await manager.save(ItemEntity, item);
```

Comment: This pointed me in the direction I want to go in. I'm inserting the item_name entities before saving the parent (item), and it works. The itemId column is filled with the correct id. Thanks for your help!