# How to save 2 entities that are related Typeorm?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I have a NestJS project that has an entity called Users. In this entity there are login related information about a user. I also have another entity called Profile, that will hold the user's name, pictures etc...

These 2 entities relates to each other, the problem is, when the user registers, I will not have any profile information yet. How can I make this happen on TypeOrm? I tried just saving the user information but when I create the profile it doesn't relate to the user.

Thanks

Here is my entities:

#### User Entity

```
import {
  BaseEntity,
  Column,
  Entity,
  JoinColumn,
  OneToOne,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
  Unique,
} from 'typeorm';
import * as bcrypt from 'bcrypt';
import { UserProfile } from './profile/user-profile.entity';

@Entity()
@Unique(['email'])
export class User extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column()
  email: string;

  @Column()
  password: string;

  @Column()
  salt: string;

  async validatePassword(password: string): Promise<boolean> {
    const hash = await bcrypt.hash(password, this.salt);
    return hash === this.password;
  }

  @Column({ type: 'timestamp', default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' })
  registration_date: Date;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  login_method: string;

  @Column()
  role: string;

  @OneToOne(() => UserProfile, (profile) => profile.user)
  @JoinColumn()
  profile: UserProfile;
}
```

#### User Repository (Save method)

```
async newUser(authCred: AuthCredentialsDTO): Promise<User> {
    const { password } = authCred;
    const userCred = new User();
    Object.assign(userCred, authCred);
    userCred.salt = await bcrypt.genSalt();
    userCred.password = await this.hashPassword(password, userCred.salt);

    try {
      await userCred.save();
      return userCred;
    } catch (error) {
      throw new InternalServerErrorException(error);
    }
  }
```

#### Profile Entity

```
import { BaseEntity, Column, Entity, OneToOne, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';
import { User } from '../user.entity';

@Entity()
export class UserProfile extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  firstName: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  lastName: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  address: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  address_comp: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  city: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  province_state: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  postal_code: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  picture: string;

  @OneToOne(() => User, (user) => user.profile)
  user: User;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrite the `User` entity to simplify it and remove unnecessary code.
Moreover I've made the following changes:

1. Set `unique: true` directly in the email column decorator.
2. `registration_date` is now @CreateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamp', update: false }) that automatically set the creation date.
3. Saving the `salt` with the `password` is a bad practice. See [this](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-good-practice-to-save-salt-with-a-password-or-should-it-be-stored-at-a-different-place-Should-it-be-encrypted-or-not).
4. Set `cascade: true` in *profile* column so when you save a `User` entity and `profile` field is *"populated"* is also saved. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55098023/typeorm-cascade-option-cascade-ondelete-onupdate/55101273#55101273).
5. Move `validatePassword(...)` in another place. Don't pollute your entity.

   1. In you DB store only the password hash.
   2. To compare a plain password with the hash stored in the DB use the `bcrypt.compare(plainPassword, hashPassword)` function.
6. Use `.create(...)` method to *"create"* an instance of an entity and set its values.

User Entity:

```js
@Entity()
export class User extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column({ unique: true })
  email: string;

  @Column()
  password: string;

  @CreateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamp' })
  registration_date: Date;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  login_method: string;

  @Column()
  role: string;

  @OneToOne(() => UserProfile, (profile) => profile.user, { cascade: true })
  @JoinColumn()
  profile: UserProfile;
}
```

User Repository:

```js
async newUser(authCred: AuthCredentialsDTO): Promise<User> {
  const entityManager = getManager();
  const { password } = authCred;

  const user = entityManager.create(User, {
    password: await hashPassword(password, await bcrypt.genSalt()),
    profile: {}
  });

  try {
    return (await entityManager.save(User, user));
  } catch (error) {
    throw new InternalServerErrorException(error);
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow! @Carlo Corradini thank you so much! I'm truly glad for your explanation... I'll buy a TypeORM course right now. Thank you so much